# I don't know how to align my popovers to button

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, popover, uipopover

i'm very new to Xcode and developing in general (my first app) and I'm wondering how I can align the popovers in swift to the button as you can see [image: here]

Answer (score 0):

When you create the popover, you also state the view that the arrow points to *and the bounds in relation to that view* that the arrow should point to. So if `n` is the neon view, then `n.bounds` is the position within the neon view to which the arrow should point, if you want to point right at it. If you want to point above it as in the picture, then adjust that value before returning it.